# gmail truncates html links on un-encoded character #

Tags: javascript, html, email

I am constructing an HTML email that includes images as links. Some target URL's have the "#" character in them, e.g.: `http://www.sigmatek-is.com/#!clients/c1a4e`

When rendered by Gmail, it truncates the above URL to just: `http://www.sigmatek-is.com`

Since I cannot use JavaScript in emails, I cannot decodeURI. How can I use such URL's that will persist in Gmail?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the workaround I eventually used, given no direct solutions found:
I used [Google URL Shortener](https://goo.gl/) to substitute the original URL's with plain URL's that Gmail accepts.